# django oscar commerce: Conflicting 'stockrecord' models in application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-oscar

I am using oscarcommerce for my django project. I want to extend the "StockRecord" model to include some more fields. So I forked the partner app as follows. (boscar is my app name)

```
python manage.py oscar_fork_app partner boscar/
```

It successfully forked and new files were added to boscar/partner folder. I added 'boscar.partner' in my installed apps.

Now I added new fields in StockRecord models as follows

boscar/partner/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from oscar.apps.partner.abstract_models import AbstractStockRecord


class StockRecord(AbstractStockRecord):
    effective_price = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    is_instock_item = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
    instock_quantity = models.IntegerField()

from oscar.apps.partner.models import *  # noqa
```

Now when I try to make migrations it shows the following error.

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'stockrecord' models in application 'partner': <class 'oscar.apps.partner.models.StockRecord'> and <class 'boscar.partner.models.StockRecord'>.
```

I already successfully forked the catalogue and order models and that are working fine. Only this "StockRecord" models showing this error.

Comment: You say "added 'boscar.partner' in my installed apps", do you do that using get_core_apps? Like:

INSTALLED_APPS = [#Other apps] + get_core_apps(['boscar.partner'])

Comment: 'corsheaders',
    'adminapi',
    'schedule'

] + get_core_apps(['boscar.partner','boscar.catalogue','boscar.wishlists',]

Comment: The next thing I would check is that you haven't directly imported that model somewhere in your code, you should either be directly importing `boscar.partner.models.StockRecord` or using `oscar.core.loading.get_model('partner', 'StockRecord')`

Comment: Please show us your full `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: @CraigLoftus, you saved my day. Thank you very much. In one of my serializer I had imported as  `code  from oscar.apps.partner.models import StockRecord  code`. Now I have changed that to `code from boscar.partner.models import  StockRecord  code`. Now It works. Thank again. Could you please explain the issue before.

Answer (score 0):

That error can occur as a result of a circular import issue associated with Oscar's support for overriding models and classes.

You need to check for places where you're importing directly from `oscar.apps.partner.models`. These should be replaced by importing from `boscar.partner.models` or using `oscar.core.loading.get_model`.